# why is my form not passing information in spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello i am passing information in a form and everything runs fine but when i fill out the form it doesnt not pass the information and i am getting this error.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'movie_id' cannot be null

the code i am using is as folow:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(Movie movie) {
    savedMovie.save(movie);
    return "redirect:/LatestMovies";
}
```

And

```
 <form th:action="@{/save}" method="post" >
    <p><input type="text" id="movie_id" name="movie_id" value="" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="movie_name" name="movie_name" value="" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="save" /></p>
     </form>
```

i belive all other code is correct becuase if i try to render the db information i have no problem.

**Update**

This is the complete html code.

```
<div class="container">   
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="LatestMovies : ${latestMovies}">
        <td th:text="${LatestMovies.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${LatestMovies.movieName}"></td>
        <td>
       <form th:action="@{/save}" method="post" th:object="${newMovie}">
<p><input type="text" id="movie_id" th:field="*{movie_Id}"/></p>
<p><input type="text" id="movie_name" th:field="*{movie_Name}"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="save" /></p>
    </form>
</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As the error says, your movie_id is null, when you are tring to save to the DB. Check why movie_id is null

Comment: ass you can see i am passing information in the form for that field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is expecting a Movie object, but it is receiving something else, which then produces a null Movie object. You need to use `th:object` in your form in order to correctly send the respective class. First, let's add a new `@ModelAttribute` to your controller, so that your form can automatically map your Movie object in your form.

**Controller**

```
// In order to use th:object in a form, we must be able to map a new entity to that form.
// In this case we return a Movie entity.
@ModelAttribute(value = "newMovie")
public Movie newMovie() {return new Movie();}
```

Now, let's change your form, so that it actually sends a Movie object.

```
<form th:action="@{/save}" method="post" th:object="${newMovie}">
    <p><input type="text" id="movie_id" th:field="*{movie_id}"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="movie_name" th:field="*{movie_name}"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="save" /></p>
</form>
```

Note that I also changed the `name` attribute in your inputs, for `th:field`. Have in mind that in order for this to work, the name of each field must match exactly the names in your objects.

**Update**

In case you want to set a default value to your form, without using `js` and since you can't combine `th:field` with `th:value`, you could set the object's attribute in your controller.

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "newMovie")
public Movie newMovie() {
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setName("Test");
    return movie;
}
```

**Update 2**

If what you want is to put the current iteration of a Thymeleaf list in your form, you can do the following.

```
<div class="container">   
<table class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr th:each="LatestMovies : ${latestMovies}">
      <td th:text="${LatestMovies.id}"></td>
      <td th:text="${LatestMovies.movieName}"></td>
      <td>
          <form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${LatestMovies}" method="post">
              <p><input type="hidden" th:value="*{id}"/></p>
              <p><input type="hidden" th:value="*{movieName}"/></p>
              <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
          </form>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i love your answer you just made it work and i have been trying 100 different approaches over the last 3 days. Now i have not seen this kind of approach anywhere and belive me 3 answers max voted said there is no way of passing information from a form in spring boot without javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Sorry if i ask you a little more but... when i try to add a value to the input it does not accept it. i am trying this 2 methods.   "<p><input type="hidden" id="movie_id" th:field="*{movie_Id}" th:attr="value = ${LatestMovies.id}"/></p>" and <input type="hidden" id="movie_id" th:field="*{movie_Id}" value = "${LatestMovies.id}"/></p> even inputing a regular information like value="123" and its not alowing to input a pre define value

Comment: I edited my answer with the extra information. Let me know if it solve your inquiry. If it does, an upvote would be great :).

Comment: once i get my reputation up to 15 belive me you will have it.   Now i did update my html code to the complete one. Your update does work but the information i want to input is the current iterration of a thymeleaf list.

Comment: I believe my new update should do the trick. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: it is not helping actually gives me some different errors but... maybe i am inserting it wrong. where should i use this code?

Comment: Could you add your html code where you are iterating through that list? That way I can give you a more clearer example.

Comment: i did an update of my full html body marked as Update

Comment: now i getting this errors: Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "LatestMovies" - line 24, col 39) and Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "LatestMovies" - line 24, col 39) and Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LatestMovies' available as request attribute

Comment: Ok, I updated my code, instead of using `th:field` use `th:value` when iterating the list. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: the information its loading ( i change to from hidden to text to verify it but... now we are back to column movie_id canot be null so the information its not passing from the form to the backend

Comment: Well, we could set the values using `js`, if that's an option, I could give you an example.

Comment: i was about to do it when you answered and i was hyped that it might was posible. my solution was to make a hidden modal form that gave the option to the user of "Are you sure you want to add"

Comment: if you have a more simple solution i am up to sugestions

Comment: I just updated my answer in your other question. I believe this will do the trick and you won't need to add any `js`. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271877/passing-thymeleaf-information-to-a-hidden-form/54279680#54279680

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mark method param with `@RequestBody` annotation.

Comment: like this? "public String save(@RequestParam Movie movie) {"

Comment: Yes but Use @RequestBody instead.

Comment: like this? "public String save(@RequestBody Movie movie) {" with this i am getting this error now There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because **the movie object you are trying to send from the form to the controller is not mapped properly**. This has as a result **the constraint of the movie_id you have in your movies table (PK not null I guess) to be violated by trying to insert a not null value** into it. If you want the object formed in the frontend page form to be binded in a java object you could try this

**front page form**

```
<form:form action="save" modelAttribute="movie" method="POST">
    <form:label path = "movie_id"> Movie id</form:label>
    <form:input path="movie_id" name="movie_id">
    <form:label path = "movie_name"> Movie name</form:label>
    <form:input path="movie_name" name="movie_name">
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form:form>
```

(you should import on your page the springframework form taglib 
    `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`)

**Save controller code**

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(@ModelAttribute("movie") Movie movie) {
savedMovie.save(movie);
return "redirect:/LatestMovies";
}
```

Of course I am assuming that your object has a similar structure like shown below

**Movie class**

```
public class Movie{
  private String movie_id; // or int or long
  private String movie_name;
  //getters setters constructors ommitted
}
```

Comment: thx for this response. i did try this approach but i did now used the taglib that could be the reason why it not worked. now saying this. in your approach how could i make hidden fields that are inputed with values of a former thymeleaf iterration?